# Verify Presence of network interface using C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, networking

Is there a way to find out if a particular interface exits using C .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getifaddrs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).  There is an example program on the manpage.  Basically you would have to just loop through the list looking for a match.  Optionally you can look at [if_nameindex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nameindex) [if_indextoname](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_indextoname) and [if_nametoindex](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_nametoindex)

Comment: Thanks Duck , I used the if_nameindex suggestion.